# Global setup in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am currently planning on using RSpec to continuously monitor some of our services. The plan is to create some tests, run them periodically and automatically alert if (when) errors are found. As many products use the same server it would make seance to create then connection once and then use the same connection for all tests.

I am not using rail, just Ruby and RSpec:

```
  -- spec_helper.rb # Setup server connections, handle errors.
  -- test1_spec.rb  # Specific tests for product one, uses server connection from spec_helper.
  -- test2_spec.rb  # Tests for product two, uses same connection as one.
  -- test3_spec.rb
```

Basically, can I create a `before :all` and `after :all` that applies to all files in the test, or do I need to repeat my connection in each test file (or put all tests in one big file)?

Comment: Have you checked out `before(:suite)`?  Maybe that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

So using @CDub's useful comment I got it working by adding

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) {$x = 'my_variable'}
end
```

to the spec_helper file.

Note that the variable must be global and each file that use the variable must import rspec_helper: `require_relative 'spec_helper'`